# Repositório online, problema com histórico de commits

Tags: git, github

Estou trabalhando em um projeto onde atualmente tenho 3 *branches* feitos assim como seus respectivos *merges* para o master.

O problema é que quando eu solicito um *push* do *master* para o repositório online o número de contribuições que tenho passa a ser somente o do dia atual e então eu perco todo o histórico de *commits* dos dias passados.

Segui umas instruções e fiz um `git push --all origin` pra enviar todos os *branches* mas não adiantou todo o histórico de contribuição ainda não aparece.

Alguém pode me dizer porque ele não está mantendo toda a movimentação feita no repositório desde seu o início?

Comment: O histórico de contribuições do GitHub só leva em consideração os _pushes_, os _commits_ locais não contam.

Comment: O git não vai fazer levar ao branch remoto nenhum commit que ele já tenha. Isso é normal - os commits do git são incrementais.

Comment: Entendi, obrigado pela resposta de vocês, mas ainda tem um problema, eu já fiz alguns pushes, e mesmo assim só exibe o que fiz hoje, estaria eu fazendo algo errado?